# Проблема с использование useReducer and useContext

Tags: веб-программирование, reactjs, react-router, jsx, react-hook

При загрузке приложение выдает ошибку

*Line 10:28:  React Hook "useReducer" is called in function "counterState" which is neither a React function component or a custom React Hook function  react-hooks/rules-of-hooks*

Код приложения

App.js

```
import React, {Component, useContext} from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import All from './All/All';
import {Route, Link} from 'react-router-dom';
import counterContext from './counterContext.js';

class App extends Component {
    constructor () {
        super();
        this.state = {
            counter: 'count',
            but: 'but-main'
        }
    }
    render () {
        const {add, sub, ass, drop, count} = useContext(counterContext);
        return (
            <All>
            <b className={this.state.counter}>{this.count}</b>
            <button onClick={this.add} className={this.state.but}>Прибавить 1</button>
            <button onClick={this.sub} className={this.state.but}>Вычесть 1</button>
            <button onClick={this.ass} className={this.state.but}>Асинхронно добавить 100</button>
            <button onClick={this.drop} className={this.state.but}>Сбросить к херам</button>
            </All>
        );
    }

}

export default App
```

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';
import {BrowserRouter} from 'react-router-dom';
import counterState from './counterState.js';

const application = (
        <counterState>
        <BrowserRouter>
        <App/>
        </BrowserRouter>
        </counterState>
    )

ReactDOM.render(application, document.getElementById('root'));
```

counterContext.js

```
import React, {createContext} from 'react';

const counterContext = createContext();

export default counterContext
```

counterState.js

```
import React, {useReducer} from 'react';
import {ADD, SUB, DROP, ASS} from './actionTypes';
import counterContext from './counterContext.js';
import counterReducer from './counterReducer.js';

const counterState = ({children}) => {
    const initialState = {
        count : 0
    }
    const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(counterReducer, initialState);

    const add = () => {
        dispatch({type: ADD})
    }
    const sub = () => {
        dispatch({type: SUB})
    }
    const ass = (number) => {
        dispatch({type: ASS})
    }
    const drop = () => {
        dispatch({type: DROP, payload: 0})
    }
    const {count} = state;
    return (
        <counterContext.Provider value={{
            add, sub, ass, drop, count
        }}>
        {children}
        </counterContext.Provider>
    );

}

export default counterState
```

counterReducer.js

```
import React from 'react';
import {ADD, SUB, DROP, ASS} from './actionTypes';

const counterReducer = (state, action) => {
    switch(action.type) {
        case ADD: return {
            count: state.count + 1
        }
        case SUB: return {
            count: state.count - 1
        }
        case ASS: return {
            count: state.count + 100
        }
        case DROP: return {
            count: action.payload
        }
        default: return state
    }
}

export default counterReducer
```

**I need some help!**

Answer (score 0):

counterState нужно писать с большой буквы если это компонент Реакт.

```
const СounterState = ({...}) => ...

<СounterState>
    ...
</СounterState>
```